# How to create a svg <path> as an object with two "d" attributes that work together, but separately?

Tags: javascript, svg, path, stenciljs

```
  convertStringToHtml(htmlString) { 
    const div = document.createElement('div')
    div.innerHTML = htmlString
    return div.firstChild
  }

  convertPathToVnode(pathString) { 
    const pathToObject = Array
    .from(pathString.attributes, ({ name, value }) => ({ name, value }))
    .reduce((acc, current) => {
      acc[current.name] = current.value
      return acc
    }, {})
    const objToVnode = h("path", pathToObject)
    return objToVnode
  }
```

These are two essential and relevant functions. The first one takes the `<path>` as an `html` string, and converts it into `html`.

The second one create an takes that `html`, extracts its `attributes`, and creates an object, which I then use `h()` to convert to a proper VNODE that I can use in Stencil.js.

The problem is that, some `svg`s have two `<path>`s. One nested inside the other. In such a case, the `convertPatoToVnode` function only gets the attributes of the first `<path>`, and not the second.
This is an image of how some `<path>`s look like:
[image: Two paths]

As you can see, they are not siblings. The second is rather nested inside the first.

What I need to do is to modify the `convertPatoToVnode` function to account for the case in which we have two `<path>`s. I am struggling to understand how to do that.

First path obj: `{fill: 'currentColor', d: 'M8.5 6a1 1 0 1 0 0-2 1 1 0 0 0 0 2Z'}`

Second path obj: `{stroke: 'currentColor', stroke-linecap: 'round', stroke-linejoin: 'round', d: 'M8.5 15.5a7 7 0 1 0 0-14 7 7 0 0 0 0 14ZM8.5 12.5v-4'}`

Even if I use `pathString.firstChild.attributes` to get the second `<path>`, I have two path objects, and even if I merge them, it doesn't work because merging the two `d` attributes into a single one consisting of the two `d` values does not form the correct icon. Both are designed to work together, not as one.

Just for your information, the returned value of `h()` is then nested inside a `<svg>`.

Does anyone have any idea how to make this work?

The paths need to be converted into VNODE, otherwise, they don't work on Stencil, which only works with VNODE.

The final Vnode obj that `h()` returns, and that I nest inside the `svg` looks like this:

[image: final vnode]

How do I account for a second `<path>` nested inside the first one?

Comment: nesting path elements is invalid. You need to fix the input files, not the processor. You can just ignore the nested paths since they will not be functional.

Comment: What do you mean? You mean nesting two `<path>s` inside one `<svg>` is invalid, or do you mean nesting one `<path>` inside another is invalid?

Comment: nesting one path inside another is invalid.

Comment: Okay, I can fix that, but let's assume I have an html string with both `<path>`s as siblings as opposed to nested. The same question remains. How do I modify the above functions to account for the possibility that there could be two `<path>`s?

Comment: @RobertLongson I can't just take the string and insert it inside the <svg>, that won't work. What I nest inside the `<svg>` needs to be a VNODE object.

Comment: if you want 2 path in your svg and want to manipulate them as one, you have to group them <g><path.../><path.../></g>. You can give an id or a class to the g <g id="xxx">...

Comment: @pierfarrugia Are you sure nesting `<g>` inside `<svg>` would work the same as nesting two `<path>`s? Also, would it work if I convert the `<g>` into a VNODE object? What would giving it an `id` do?

Comment: if you want to manipulate the svg by itself, just put path one after one <path.../><path.../>. If you want to manipulate several elements inside 1 svg as it would be 1 element, group them. and use the group. I don't really know regarding stencil, I'm not using it. It's general way of using, manipulating svg

Comment: I already fixed it. The main issue was that the `<path>`s were self-closed which is invalid, and resulted in the second `<path>` getting nested inside the first. What I did was to just grab both, turn them into Vnodes, and then nest them inside the `<svg>` the way I did up until one with only one `<path>`.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue was that the `<path>`s were self-closed which is invalid, and resulted in the second `<path>` getting nested inside the first.
What I did was to just grab both, turn them into Vnodes, and then nest them inside the `<svg>` the way I did up until now with only one `<path>`.

Comment: Self-closing paths like `<path d="" />` are compliant to the svg specs. If stencil.js can't parse them please clarify

Comment: I was just wondering about this myself. Is `<path>` not explicit by default? Is it really self-closing?